# Does Flutter HiveDB lose data when updating app on the play store?

Tags: android, flutter, updates, mobile-application

Consider you have a Flutter app that uses HiveDB for local storage. It has been deployed to the play store and has many users. It saves local user data like progress, high scores, todos etc using HiveDB.

If you update your app and release an update in the play store, will the database lose its data?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No. Unless the storage of the app is cleared or the app is uninstalled, updating the app will not affect stored data in Hive db.